# Undo or revert an accidentally reverted pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

So, I submitted a pull request to bitbucket, and after approval I merged it like I always do. however, I accidentally reverted it after the merge somehow.

I've found ways to fix a branch in this instance but I don't know what to do for a pull request.

I can see the commit for the revert, but what's the best method here? The new pull request for the revert shows everything that I pushed/added as deletes now so I want to basically undo the whole thing and get it back to the original commit and merge so that I can pull on production.

Comment: I feel `git revert merge-commit-sha` is best. As it is already merged, it will show everything that u pushed/added as deleted. But thats okay as you are undoing

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something similar on Github I hope that may help you

- Under your repository name, click  Pull requests.
- In the "Pull Requests" list, click the pull request you'd like to revert.
- Near the bottom of the pull request, click Revert.
- Merge the resulting pull request. For more information, see "Merging
  a pull request."